# jsPsych html-keyboard-response keyboard locks up

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, jspsych

I am working on a JavaScript app with a jsPsych experiment that uses an html-keyboard-response trial. A word is displayed on the screen for 500ms, and then the user responds with the left or right arrow key. Trial results are saved to a Firestore database. The app also uses store.session extensively.

When deployed on Chromebooks in multiple classroom of 20 kids each, up to 3-7 in each classroom saw a bug where the app appeared to freeze and stop accepting arrow key input. It was still possible to hit Esc to exit full screen and kill the tab.

There are minimal images after the instructions complete, so I don’t think it’s a caching or preload issue. Has anyone seen something similar? What would be the easiest way to automate the testing of this to try and reproduce it?

Comment: Can you share the code for the trial that sometimes froze?